# Scrolling on click event in a HTML email Listserv

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to send an HTML email with link on it that would scroll the client's browser at a specific portion in the email. How do I implement that... or at least where would I get at tutorial that would help me out? I'm thinking Javascript and jQuery.

Comment: you're unlikely to find any decent solution to this. HTML email is sketchy at best without any javascript and most email clients will not run any scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need javascript of jQuery for that. Just have an anchor name in the url with `#`. Once the page loads it will automatically scroll to that anchor on the page.

Comment: you only need jQuery for "smooth" scrolling: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/